# How to set the textbox border color red when validation fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have got a task to set red color border for text box when the validation fails in .net mvc 4.

BExtensionMethods.cs

```
    public static string GetTextBoxColor(this ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
    {
        string textBoxColor = string.Empty;
        int count = 1;
        var errorKeys = (from item in ModelState
                         where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                         select item.Key).ToList();
        foreach (var item in errorKeys)
        {
            textBoxColor += string.Format("{0}.{1}</br>", count, item);
            count++;
        }
        return textBoxColor;
    }
```

Here the json object contains the values.How can I filter it?

Comment: Did you try setting the red color where you are calling alert?

Comment: @AshwinSingh-How to filter the values from this jso object?

Comment: Json can directly be converted to javascript objects which you can use to get the value. http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Comment: @AshwinSingh-but here I used ajax function

Comment: What is the Json object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static List<string> GetTextBoxColor(this ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
    {
        string textBoxColor = string.Empty;
        int count = 1;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        var errorKeys = (from item in ModelState
                         where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                         select item.Key.Substring(item.Key.LastIndexOf('.')).Trim('.')).ToList();
        foreach (var item in errorKeys)
        {
            textBoxColor += string.Format("{0}.{1}</br>", count, item);
            list.Add(item);
            count++;
        }
        return list;

    }
```

Answer (score 20):

```
if ($('#TextBoxID').val() == '') {
    $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', 'red');
}
else {
    $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', '');
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.

Answer (score 17):

You need to make a css class like that:

```
.errorClass { border:  1px solid red; }
```

And add it to your textbox whith jQuery:

```
$("#myTextBox").addClass('errorClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the below code in your project u will get to know, i'm using purely bootstrap and jquery here.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
/**
 * Override feedback icon position
 * See http://formvalidation.io/examples/adjusting-feedback-icon-position/
 */
#eventForm .dateContainer .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
    right: -15px;
}
</style>

<form id="eventForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Event</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Start date</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5 dateContainer">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="startDatePicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" />
                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">End date</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5 dateContainer">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="endDatePicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" />
                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startDatePicker')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the start date field
            $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'startDate');
        });

    $('#endDatePicker')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'endDate');
        });

    $('#eventForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                startDate: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The start date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            max: 'endDate',
                            message: 'The start date is not a valid'
                        }
                    }
                },
                endDate: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The end date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            min: 'startDate',
                            message: 'The end date is not a valid'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            if (data.field === 'startDate' && !data.fv.isValidField('endDate')) {
                // We need to revalidate the end date
                data.fv.revalidateField('endDate');
            }

            if (data.field === 'endDate' && !data.fv.isValidField('startDate')) {
                // We need to revalidate the start date
                data.fv.revalidateField('startDate');
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This answer could've used a lot more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one textbox and id is known to you , you can use the @PanzerKadaver solution. Otherwise i would suggest to return in the json it self the ids of the textboxes which you want to make the red . Then loop through it and add the error class on the client side.

Comment: My all data comes under this variable- objRenewableEnergy.How can I filter the values from objRenewableEnergy

Comment: use can use the json notation result.renewableEnergy and loop through it. In case you want to see the exact JSON , using the developer tool of the IE using F12 and see the structure of the JSON coming with all the properties. You can loop usin $.each of the jquery

Comment: for (var n = 0; n < objRenewableEnergy;n++ ) { } is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

`result.renewableEnergy` will give you the value you need. Any other properties of the `objRenewableEnergy` can be accessed by `result.renewableEnergy.property`

Comment: Yes..But its a combination of all values.I want to filter it.how can I?

Comment: Is its a list or a collection you can use for loop to access values and find the one you need. for(var n in result.renewableEnergy.values){}

Comment: for (var n = 0; n < objRenewableEnergy;n++ ) { }  is it correct?